# Issues with generating Standard Normal Random Variable via A-R Algorithm

Tags: matlab

This is quite a specific question, but I am using the Acceptance-Rejection Algorithm to try and generate Standard Normal random variables from two mirrored Exponentials. The code is as follows:

```
N=10000;
a=1.315;
acceptances = 0;
no_of_loops = 0;
while acceptances<N
    no_of_loops = no_of_loops + 1;
    U1 = rand;
    U2 = rand;
    U3 = rand;
if U1>0.5
    Y=log(U2);
    if U3<=(1/a)*(sqrt(2/pi))*(exp((-(Y^2)/2)-Y))  % Acceptance condition
        acceptances = acceptances + 1;
        X(no_of_loops) = Y;
    end
elseif U1<0.5
    Y=-log(U2);
    if U3<=(1/a)*(sqrt(2/pi))*(exp((-(Y^2)/2)+Y)) % Acceptance condition
        acceptances = acceptances + 1;
        X(no_of_loops) = Y;
    end
end
end

mean_X = mean(X) % Mean is close to 0 as expected
variance_X = (var(X)) % Variance is coming out to be 0.7 rather than 1
```

The `variance_X` is coming out as 0.7 rather than 1. I know the fact that I am using Exponential's isn't the issue as that is a tried and tested algorithm, but I think my code may be wrong. Thank You.

I am using the same idea as on Pg.3 of this [PDF](http://www.columbia.edu/~ks20/4703-Sigman/4703-07-Notes-ARM.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your algo a few times, if you do so you'll notice it gives a variance around .7 the first time indeed, but if you don't clear and run it again the variance gets around 1...
This is because you are leaving `0` in your `X` vector. Written as it is now, if your candidate `i` is rejected then you leave `X(i)` to `0` and move on to `i+1`, you shouldn't do that, you need to generate samples until one is accepted as `X(i)`, so you can easily fix your code by forgetting about `no_of_loops` and write new samples in `X` as:

```
X(acceptances) = Y;
```

That way you won't leave the blanks (hence `0)` that were decreasing the variance.